# Validation of the Polish and foreign mobile phone number

Tags: php, validation

I have the following problem, I need to create a validator for a Polish and foreign mobile phone number, but I have no idea how to do it. Validation of the Polish number works fine, unfortunately I do not know how to add foreign numbers to it. My code:

```
$result = preg_match('/^((\+|0\s?0)\s?4\s?8)?[\s\-0-9]+$/', $phone);
    if (1 === $result) {
        $phone = preg_replace('/(\s|\-)/', '', $phone);

        if (null === $phone) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('preg_replace error: %s', preg_last_error()));
        }

        $result = preg_match('/^((\+|00)48)?[0-9]{9}$/', $phone);
        if (1 === $result) {
            return;
        }
    } elseif (false === $result) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('preg_match error: %s', preg_last_error()));
    }
```

It could be done so that if only 9 digits are given, we consider this to be the Polish number and we receive +48. in all other cases, we require a prefix starting with either 00 or +.

Comment: What is the specification of foreign mobile number?

Comment: I add additional info to post.

Comment: There are a lot of types of foreign numbers man. You should add an option for the person to select it her phone is Polish or not, if it's Polish, adopt the validation, if not, ignore it (or add a type for each country)

Comment: just in case you need all the country code you can get it here https://countrycode.org/

Comment: and maybe you can use this `https://restcountries.eu` for your problem